# alternatives to read.csv(textConnection())

Tags: r, pipe, rcurl, throttling

I am downloading a 120mb csv file from webserver using `read.csv(textConnection(binarydata1))` and this is painfully slow. I tried `pipe()`, like this `read.csv(pipe(binarydata1))` I am getting an error `Error in pipe(binarydata1) : invalid 'description' argument`. Any help regarding this issue is much appricated.

***@jeremycg,  @hrbrmstr***

*Suggestion*

fread from the data.table package.

local storage via download.file or functions in curl or httr and use data.table::fread like @jeremycg suggested or readr::read_csv

*Response*

The csv file i am dealing with is in binary format, so I am converting this to standard format using these functions

```
t1 = getURLContent(url,userpwd,httpauth = 1L, binary=TRUE)
t2 = readBin(t1, what='character', n=length(t1)/4)
```

when I try `fread(t2)` after converting binary to standard format i get an error

Error in fread(t61) :

```
'input' must be a single character string containing a 
 file name, a command, full path to a file, a URL starting 
 'http://' or 'file://', or the input data itself
```

If i try fread directly without converting binary to standard format then no problem it works, if I try converting binary to standard format it does not work

Comment: try `fread` from the `data.table` package. If you can, download the file locally first.

Comment: this may help http://www.biostat.jhsph.edu/~rpeng/docs/R-large-tables.html

Comment: I'd save that puppy to real, local storage via `download.file` or functions in `curl` or `httr` and use `data.table::fread` like @jeremycg suggested or `readr::read_csv`

Comment: @jeremycg , @ hrbrmstr I have added comments to y'all suggestion below my question :)

Comment: Check the url of `t61`, also what *is* `t61`?

Comment: @RichardScriven, ah typo, it was supposed to be t1, fixed it now.

Comment: Doesn't `getURLContent()` return a raw vector?  That my not be the right function for the task using `fread()`

Comment: @RichardScriven you are absolutely correct. `getURLContent()` returns a large raw vector of size 120mb, `fred()` does not work in this situation and `textConnection()` takes forever

Comment: Maybe you can benefit from this discussion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1727772/quickly-reading-very-large-tables-as-dataframes-in-r

Answer (score 0):

Even though the question is 4 years old it helped me with my current problem, where I also have a 300MB connection where read.csv took ages.

I found the `vroom` function from package `vroom` helpful here. It stored my data like a charme. It took one minute for my data where I don't even know if the `read.csv(textConnection...)` would get me a result (I usually terminated R after 30min. with no result).